# iOS app rejected due to Missing In-App Purchase...how long until acceptance?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

Recently we submitted an app to the App Store that utilizes In-App Purchase. We have a few different purchases available, one of which was not submitted during the initial submission process. The app was rejected for this reason:

> We've completed the review of your app, but cannot post this version to the App Store because it did not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines, as detailed below:
>
> Missing In App Purchase

We then submitted the missing In-App Purchase. Has anyone had experience with the length of time for acceptance once this step is taken? Does it take the usual 7 - 10 days that Apple estimates?

Comment: it's apple. it's not going to be quick, i can tell you that.

Comment: Currently experiencing the same thing with Apple. Done an update with the inclusion of in-app purchases. So far it's been in review for over 1 month. Even asked for expedited review, 2 weeks later finally got response ... rejected. Prior to this, approvals were usually within a week or two.

Comment: Do you know what one is supposed to do to solve this "In-app purchase" problem? My app has auto-renewable subscriptions, but got rejected. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to know. In my experience Apple's review process timing is erratic and impossible to predict. I've had reviews take anywhere from 1 hour to 2 weeks.